# Referencing same hdfs table in my 50 union all statements in impala which is resulting in memory issues

Tags: memory, hive, impala, union-all

Referencing same hdfs table joins in my 50 union all statements in impala which is resulting in memory issues

```
Select a,case statement
From a inner join b
On a=b

Union all

Select a,case statement
From a inner join b
On a=b

Union all

Select a,case statement
From a inner join b
On a=b

Union all

Select a,case statement
From a inner join b
On a=b
```

Comment: Please mention exact error (error stack) you are seeing.

Comment: does this actually reflect your current query or is just an example? I am wondering why use union all on top of same table